# Expectation of a function of sorted uniform random variables

Tags: pr.probability

Let $a,b,c>0$ with $a>b$ and let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be a collection of independent uniform samples from the unit interval.  Assume that we re-order the samples so that $X_1\leq X_2 \leq \cdots \leq X_n$, and then let $Z_i := X_{i+1}-X_i$ denote the differences between neighbors.  My question is, is there any way to compute the expectation of the sum $$\sum_i\max\{ aZ_i~,~bZ_i+c \}$$?  This seems difficult but not intractably so.

Comment: If $n$ is large, then $\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ are close to the points of an intensity $n$ Poisson process on $[0,1]$. In that case, $Z_i$ is approximately exponential with parameter $n$, and you can estimate $\mathbb E\max(aZ_i,bZ_i+c)$.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, awesome!  @AnthonyQuas, do you have any recommendations for a reference?

Comment: Sorry. I don't really have much of a reference. But: any book at all on Poisson processes will prove that conditional on the number of particles in a region being $n$, they are i.i.d. and uniform. If the intensity is $n$, you know there are $n\pm \sqrt n$ particles, so this is not too much of a stretch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's throw in $X_0=0$ and $X_{n+1}=1$. Then there are $n+1$ variables $(Z_i)$ lying on the simplex $\{z\in\mathbb R^{n+1}_+\colon z_1+\ldots+z_{n+1}=1\}$. The distribution is uniform. Each $Z_i$ has the same marginal distribution with density $f_Z(z)=(n+1)(1-z)^n$. So your expectation is just $(n+1)\int_0^1 (n+1)\max(az,bz+c)(1-z)^n\,dz$, which is easy to evaluate explicitly.

If you don't like having $Z_1$ and $Z_{n+1}$, the sum is over $n-1$ identically distributed random variables (not independent, but expectation doesn't care), so the pre-factor $n+1$ is replaced with $n-1$.

Comment: Do you have any reference for this answer? Thank you. Mo